# how to represent "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" as java string?

Tags: ethereumj, web3j, java

How can I represent the this string `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"` in java? The first character seems the length of `'Ethereum Signed Message:\n'` string but it is escaped.

What I'm trying to do is to get the same sha3 hash for a given string using web3.sha3() and Web3j Hash.sha3() with the above prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent that in Java as `"\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"`.

And I think I was trying to do the same thing as you are with handling web3 signed messages in web3j, you can see how I got that working here: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/222